# My workstation is not booting at all - TRX40 AORUS XTREME

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I was working on my workstation when suddenly it turned off by itself and when turning it on again I get the error in the image link below which leads to entering emergency mode and I cannot boot to ubuntu again.
[image]

So I pressed on the cmos on the back of the tower but when I did that it stopped booting at all, I opened my tower and I found this red led on my TRX40 AORUS XTREME you can see all the images of my workstation in this link:
Any advice please?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (ACPI BIOS Error) is a hardware error. A likely cause is Memory.

Get memtest86.exe , make a bootable USB key and test Memory. Run at least two complete tests.

After that, get the Board manufacturer's Hardware Test App and run a complete set of hardware tests.

If you cannot run tests, that suggests a serious motherboard error.  You need to get the machine serviced if this is the case.

Comment: One thing I have seen is DRAM error.  I really think it is time to get this machine serviced.

Comment: You mean "you have see" from my photos or from other workstations you had before?

Comment: I looked up the meaning and above is what I found. It does indicate a significant hardware error.

Comment: I have looked at it and will continue to do so. Not being able to start from a USB key is somewhat concerning.